# MVC3 String validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

basically I want to validate whether or not a text box is a certain day of the week.

do any of the dataannotations cover this or is this something i need to run under a for loop somewhere else.

If the latter is the case do I carry this in the model.designer.cs or within the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the regular expression data annotation + mvc's built in validation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx#Y2063